# libgdx to windows phone using bridge

Tags: libgdx

Windows Phone got my attention recently with making iOS and Android apps convertible to Windows Phone apps using Windows Bridge. I am eager to know if libgdx support translation to windows phone apps with Bridge tools? Has anyone any experience with it?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the bridge is under construction still so you're not likely to get much feedback here.  LIBGDX hasn't concentrated on Window's phone, but I think they've created an x86 DLL for some of their unmanaged code a while back.  Not sure on the status of that.

I used a similar bridge technology for Blackberry in the past.  The process was simple and only required installing plugins and executing a conversion tool on my Android APK.  No code changes.

However the site for the Window's phone bridge says minimal code changes may be required.  I'd speculate the process will be extremely simple so as to encourage releases of popular apps onto their platform.  If Microsoft makes the process complicated, developers aren't going to bother.